# VHDL: Component in Testbench provides no Output

Tags: vhdl

I wrote RTC Timer. It is working, however then I put it into testbench (use it as component) - I get no outputs in simulator. I am using Quartus Waveform Editor to perform ModelSim simulation. [Waveform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL3Ts.jpg)
Testbench Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;

entity rtc is 
port
(
    nRST        : in std_logic;
    clk         : in std_logic;
    Seconds     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    Minutes     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    Hours       : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
);
end rtc;

architecture Behavioral of rtc is

constant CLK_FREQ : integer := 2;

    component rtc_timer is
    generic(CLK_FREQ : integer);
    port
    (
        nRST        : in std_logic;
        clk         : in std_logic;
        Seconds     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        Minutes     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        Hours       : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

begin
    RTC1: rtc_timer
    generic map( CLK_FREQ => CLK_FREQ )
    port map
    (
        nRST        => nRST,
        clk         => clk,
        Seconds     => Seconds,
        Minutes     => Minutes,
        Hours       => Hours
    );
end Behavioral;
```

Real Time Clock Timer (tested separately-working as expected).[Waveform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q14vU.jpg)
Component Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL; -- Enables Adding

entity rtc_timer is
generic( CLK_FREQ : integer :=2);
port
( 
    nRST        : in std_logic;
    clk         : in std_logic;
    Seconds     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    Minutes     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    Hours       : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
);
end rtc_timer;

architecture Behavioral of rtc_timer is
signal counter : integer;
signal sec      : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
signal min      : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
signal hr       : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

begin
    process(clk, nRST) 
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            -- Negative Reset Signal
            if nRST = '0' then
                counter <= -1;  -- To account very first clk
                sec     <= (others => '0');
                min     <= (others => '0');
                hr      <= (others => '0');
            elsif counter = CLK_FREQ - 1 then
                counter <= 0;

                if sec = 59 then
                    sec <= (others => '0');

                    if min = 59 then
                        min <= (others => '0');

                        if hr = 23 then
                            hr <= (others => '0');
                        else hr <= hr + 1;
                        end if;

                    else min <= min + 1;
                    end if;

                else sec <= sec + 1;
                end if;

            else counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;

        end if; 

        Seconds <= sec;
        Minutes <= min;
        Hours   <= hr;  
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: 1/ How do you know it is working if you have not tested it?  2/ Where is the rest of your code, e.g. where is you test-bench? 3/ The code above, in my eyes, is totally superfluous. It just adds a wrapper where you set a generic.  It does not offer anything extra.

Comment: I tested it separately https://imgur.com/a/eekAwN9. I plan to reuse component for bigger design therefore it is important that wrapper is working.

Comment: I think what @Oldfart is asking for is the TB code to be able to test the whole of your design, not the reasoning behind the wrapping code.

Comment: I am new in VHDL. I tested it using Quartus Waveform Editor. In editor set clk to counting and nRST to high after some clk cycles. I have no other testbech code.

Comment: I exported TB from Quartus [Link] (https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4NUM). On ModelSim It runs, however Seconds changes on wrong edge of clk. This is strange as on Quartus I tested component alone it runs fine. Any idea why code does not sim on Quartus and why I get change on a wrong egde of clk in ModelSim?

Comment: Move your assignments from the internal signals to the out ports from this process, either to concurrent assignment statements or a separate process. They'll only be updated when the process resumes (here the clk edge) during simulation. You could alternatively add sec, min, hours to the sensitivity list of this process (doesn't hurt it's fully synchronous otherwise).

Comment: The rules for constructing a wait list are found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.2 Wait statement.

Comment: Thanks for answers. @user1155120 indeed this solves wrong edge issue. I solved no output problem by creating new vwf file in Quartus. Now it runs, however produces different result regarding clk edge (with wrong code shows changes on rising edge as well). Because of this I assume is better to use ModelSim directly.